# Have troubles with ocaml

Tags: syntax, ocaml

I have some problems with OCAML I wrote this:

```
let visibility_graph observation memory =
  Graph.add_node memory.graph observation.position
  Graph.add_node memory.graph observation.spaseship;
```

but it's not working. However this is working:

```
let visibility_graph observation memory = 
  Graph.add_node memory.graph observation.position
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't give enough information to give a full answer. However the code you show is completely consistent with your error reports. The first example appears to consist of two expressions (function calls) with no separator between them. To execute two expressions sequentially, you need a semicolon (`;`) between them.

The semicolon at the end of the first example appears to be misplaced. Things might work (depending on what the rest of your code looks like) if you just move this semicolon to the end of the previous line.

The second example looks like a ligitimate function defintion. Of course it's difficult to tell without knowing the definitions of all the identifiers used.